# Logging all error when running batch file

Tags: batch-file, logging

I need to log all error from .bat file that has been created, please help.
This is because it goes over thousands of txt files, but i need all the error to be logged if it happens.

```
:start 
del %TEMP%\*.txt* /f /s /q
sqlite3 D.db "Delete from Dis"
sqlite3 D.db "Delete from De"
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for %%j in (*.*) do (
set filename=%%~nj
set filename=!filename:.=_!
set filename=!filename: =_!
if not "!filename!"=="%%~nj" ren "%%j" "!filename!%%~xj")
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir/b "%~dp0\*.txt"') do 
        (set file=%%a
        echo "!file!"
        call :readfile !file!)
 ENDLOCAL 
:readfile
sqlite3 D.db ".read %file%"
echo %counter%
set /a counter=counter+1
:exit.
sqlite3 D.db < View.txt
sqlite3 -header -csv D.db "select * from x;" > Test.csv
goto :EOF
```

Need a csv or text file with all error logged when running the batch file.

Comment: Run the batch file with `FileName.bat 2>"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Errors.log"` and all errors output to handle __STDERR__ are redirected into file `Errors.log` on your Windows desktop. See also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Comment: but i need the file in the same directory as all the other files.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be too difficult for you to work out that removing `%UserProfile%\Desktop\ ` will prevent it from going onto your desktop!

Comment: ah fixed.. thanks by the way is there anyway to run it from the original bat file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with some, *possibly pertinent*, commands having their STDERR redirected to a file named `Errors.log`.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

:Start 
(   Del /A /F /Q /S "%TEMP%\*.txt"
    SQLite3 D.db "Delete from Dis"
    SQLite3 D.db "Delete from De") 2>"Errors.log"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where ".:*.*.*" ".:* *.*" 2^>NUL')Do (
    Set "FileName=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "FileName=!FileName:.=_!"
    Set "FileName=!FileName: =_!"
    Ren "%%A" "!FileName!%%~xA" 2>>"Errors.log"
    EndLocal)

Set "Counter=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "%~dp0*.txt" 2^>NUL')Do (
    Set /A Counter+=1
    Call Echo %%Counter%%. "%%A"
    (   SQLite3 D.db ".read %%A"
        SQLite3 D.db<"View.txt"
        SQLite3 -header -csv D.db "select * from x;">"Test.csv"
    ) 2>>"Errors.log")

GoTo :EOF
```

As you can see, I have modified your script a little and used delayed expansion in the upper [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) and a pseudo `Call` in the lower one, *for the updating increment*. I have not modified things such a locations because it is unclear to me whether you're supposed to be working in `%TEMP%`, the batch file directory, `%~dp0`, or the current directory, *(as you did not `set` one in your code effectively using the current directory in your first [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop))*.

---

Alternatively, you could just use `Call` to redirect all STDERR to `Errors.log`:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Call :Start 2>"Errors.log"
GoTo :EOF
:Start 
Del /A /F /Q /S "%TEMP%\*.txt"
SQLite3 D.db "Delete from Dis"
SQLite3 D.db "Delete from De"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where ".:*.*.*" ".:* *.*" 2^>NUL')Do (
    Set "FileName=%%~nA"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "FileName=!FileName:.=_!"
    Set "FileName=!FileName: =_!"
    Ren "%%A" "!FileName!%%~xA"
    EndLocal)
Set "Counter=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "%~dp0*.txt" 2^>NUL')Do (
    Set /A Counter+=1
    Call Echo %%Counter%%. "%%A"
    SQLite3 D.db ".read %%A"
    SQLite3 D.db<"View.txt"
    SQLite3 -header -csv D.db "select * from x;">"Test.csv")
GoTo :EOF
```